# difference between 2 dates in dd/mm/yy format for sharepoint calculated columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

difference between 2 dates in dd/mm/yy format for sharepoint calculated columns, I have two columns start and end date in datetime format.what formula to apply for  total date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DATEDIF()` function, like this:

```
=DATEDIF([FirstDateColumn], [SecondDateColumn], "D")
```

The last argument, the `D`, makes the difference return as number of days. To return other units, such as the number of complete months in the period, read the documentation for the `DATEDIF` function [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c).

You should probably check if any of the date columns are empty before trying to calculate the difference, to prevent any error messages:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([FirstDateColumn]), ISBLANK([SecondDateColumn])), "", DATEDIF([FirstDateColumn], [SecondDateColumn], "D"))
```

I found this information in [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178327/calculated-column-for-differences-between-two-dates-with-blank-check) on the SharePoint Stack Exchange.

Comment: the output in same date format like from start date to end date difference is period  2 years  2months 2 days

Comment: I apologise but I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Are you saying that neither Michael's nor my solution works for you?

Comment: sorry, i tried both but the output i'm trying is in "02 year 02 months 2 days format" is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Just use `[end date]-[start date]` would get the difference between 2 dates, you don't have to use special formula.

[image]

Comment: the output in same date format like from start date to end date difference is period  2 years  2months 2 days